# How to force table to have equal dimensions?

Tags: r

How can I force the dimensions of a table to be equal in **R**?

For example:

```
a <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,6)
c <- table(a,b)

print(c)
#   b
#a   1 2 3 5 6
#  0 1 0 0 0 0
#  1 0 1 1 0 0
#  2 0 0 1 0 0
#  3 0 0 2 1 0
#  4 0 0 2 1 0
#  5 0 0 2 0 1
```

However, I am looking for the following result:

```
print(c)
#   b
#a   0 1 2 3 4 5 6
#  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
#  1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
#  2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
#  3 0 0 0 2 0 1 0
#  4 0 0 0 2 0 1 0
#  5 0 0 0 2 0 0 1
#  6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: What language are you using?!

Comment: since when do we choose which assignment operators people can use and how to (unnecessarily) use the `print` function, @AEBilgrau ?

Comment: @rawr Sorry. I didn't know this was considered bad mannered or offensive. I find that `=` is unanimously discuraged as an assignment operator in all R style guides for a number of reasons. The addition of `print` (and deletion of the prompt `>`) and commenting the output was just to make the code more readable (and more easy to copy) as the `a` and `b` appears as dimensionnames just below the object `c`. Should and can I revert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using factors. `table` doesn't know the levels of your variable unless you tell it in some way!

```
a <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,6)

a <- factor(a, levels = 0:6)
b <- factor(b, levels = 0:6)
table(a,b)
#   b
#a   0 1 2 3 4 5 6
#  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
#  1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
#  2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
#  3 0 0 0 2 0 1 0
#  4 0 0 0 2 0 1 0
#  5 0 0 0 2 0 0 1
#  6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

*Edit* The general way to force a square cross-tabulation is to do something like

```
x <- factor(a, levels = union(a, b))
y <- factor(b, levels = union(a, b))
table(x, y)
```

Comment: Great, this works like a charm and I appreciate the `union()` idea.