# Forcing tables to have equal dimensions while using lapply

Tags: r, histogram, data-visualization, transition, lapply

I am trying to plot the frequency vs. number of transitions between states for 150 individuals. For this, lapply was used in order to generate transition tables for every individual. However, since some individuals have only very few transitions or no transitions at all, the resulting tables differ from each other in the number of rows/columns. Consequently, I am getting an "incorrect number of dimensions" error when I'm trying to extract the number of transitions in order to plot them. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245932/how-to-force-table-to-have-equal-dimensions) thread, but I was not successful applying the solution to my case.

Here is my current code:

```
n_STATEs <- 4

data <- read.csv("transitiondata.csv")
transitions <- by(data,data$ID,
                  function(xx)data.frame(ID=head(xx$ID,-1),
                                         TIME=tail(xx$TIME,-1),
                                         FROM=head(xx$STATE,-1),
                                         TO=tail(xx$STATE,-1)))
transition_table <- lapply(transitions,function(xx)with(xx,table(FROM,TO)))
min_n_transitions <- min(unlist(transition_table))
max_n_transitions <- max(unlist(transition_table))
max_freq <- 150  

par(mfrow=rep(n_STATEs,2),mai=c(.4,.4,.4,.1))
for ( from in 1:n_STATEs ) {
  for ( to in 1:n_STATEs ) {
    sapply(transition_table,"[",from,to)
    hist(foo,freq=TRUE,
         xlim=c(min_n_transitions,max_n_transitions),
         ylim=c(0,max_freq),xlab="",ylab="",
         main=paste("From",from,"to",to),las=1,col="lightgray")
  }
}
```

[Here](https://app.box.com/s/qtgfn0xehiwfga3ql4dsozl8y0zhjz4g) is the dataset. I have also tried getting the transition numbers without using lapply (see the answer in my [previous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/392147/236675) thread) but this approach also counts the transition between the last and the first time point within one individual which does not make any sense.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Code fixed.

---

Another approach is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647763/make-all-elements-of-a-list-equal-in-dimensions). The error message is gone but however, maybe because of the different sorting of rows and columns, the transition counts are obviously wrong. The current code looks like this:

```
n_STATEs <- 4

    data <- read.csv("transitiondata.csv")
    transitions <- by(data,data$ID,
                      function(xx)data.frame(ID=head(xx$ID,-1),
                                             TIME=tail(xx$TIME,-1),
                                             FROM=head(xx$STATE,-1),
                                             TO=tail(xx$STATE,-1)))
    transition_table <- lapply(transitions,function(xx)with(xx,table(FROM,TO)))
cols <- unique(unlist(sapply(transition_table, colnames)))
rows <- unique(unlist(sapply(transition_table, rownames)))
result <- lapply(transition_table, function(m) {
  missingrows <- setdiff(rows, rownames(m))
  missingcols <- setdiff(cols, colnames(m))
  rbind(cbind(m,
              structure(matrix(0, nrow=nrow(m), ncol=length(missingcols)),
                        dimnames=list(NULL, missingcols))),
        structure(matrix(0, nrow=length(missingrows), ncol=length(cols)),
                  dimnames=list(missingrows)))
})
min_n_transitions <- min(unlist(result))
    max_n_transitions <- max(unlist(result))
    max_freq <- 150  

    par(mfrow=rep(n_STATEs,2),mai=c(.4,.4,.4,.1))
    for ( from in 1:n_STATEs ) {
      for ( to in 1:n_STATEs ) {
        sapply(result,"[",from,to)
        hist(foo,freq=TRUE,
             xlim=c(min_n_transitions,max_n_transitions),
             ylim=c(0,max_freq),xlab="",ylab="",
             main=paste("From",from,"to",to),las=1,col="lightgray")
      }
    }
```

Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to declare `FROM` and `TO` as factors and set all ocurring states as `levels` this should give you zero cells in the tables for levels that don't occur.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. Maybe I have implemented it wrongly, I am not that experienced with R. It looks like this:
`transition_table <- lapply(transitions,function(xx)with(xx,table(FROM,TO)))

tran1<-factor(transition_table$FROM, levels = 1:4)

tran2<-factor(transition_table$TO, levels = 1:4)

table(tran1,tran2)` However, I do not get the proper tables.

Comment: I have also tried the solution from this thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647763/make-all-elements-of-a-list-equal-in-dimensions). I do not get the error message anymore, but the counted number of transitions is wrong. Maybe it is due to the resulting differences in the ordering of rows/columns. Are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative solution. Using [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391035/visualization-of-the-number-of-transitions-between-states/392147#392147) code, I also got transition counts between the last and first time point within one ID. However, with `arrange` and `subset` I could get rid of this strange behavior. The current code looks like this:

```
transitions <-  data.frame(ID=head(data$ID,-1),
                           TIME=tail(data$TIME, -1),FROM=head(data$STATE,-1),
                           TO=tail(data$STATE,-1))

tran1<-arrange(transitions, ID, TIME)
tran2<-subset(tran1, TIME!=0)
transition_table <- with(tran2,table(FROM,TO,ID))
min_n_transitions <- min(unlist(transition_table))
max_n_transitions <- max(unlist(transition_table))
max_freq <- 150 
bins <- c(-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5)
par(mfrow=rep(4,2),mai=c(.3,.3,.3,.1))
for ( from in 1:4 ) {
  for ( to in 1:4 ) {
    foo <- transition_table[from,to,]
    hist(foo,freq=TRUE,
         breaks=bins,
         xlim=c(-.5,max_n_transitions),
         ylim=c(0,max_freq),xlab="",ylab="",
         main=paste("From",from,"to",to),las=1,col="lightgray")
    mtext('Number of transitions', side = 1, outer = TRUE, line = 2)
    mtext('Frequency', side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 1.5)

  }
}
```